# Wordpress Ajax - get Function and JSON?

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress

can somebody tell me why i get a result in JSON with the first code and not with the second?

First:

```
       jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data:{
                    action : 'a2m_add_vote',
                    post_id: jQuery('input[name="a2m_post_id"]').val(),
                    answer_option: answer_number
                   },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                },
              error: function(errorThrown){
                   alert('error');
                   console.log(errorThrown);
              }
         });
```

Second:

```
       jQuery.get(
            ajax_object.ajax_url,
            {
                action : 'a2m_add_vote',
                post_id: jQuery('input[name="a2m_post_id"]').val(),
                answer_option: answer_number
            },function(data) {
                alert(data);
                },'JSON');
```

Comment: your dataType is JSON `dataType: 'JSON'` ? which means you expect to receive JSON data back. If you do not specify it, jQuery will try to make an intelligent guess at what it may be.

Comment: Yes, but the php script behind returns data which is encoded with json_encode...

Comment: Ok? `json_encode()` in php returns a JSON representation of a the value that it encodes. so if you take an array and run `json_encode` on it, it will return back that same array in JSON.